# Что использовать для реализации отмены рекламы и подписки на увежомления?

Tags: android

Хочу сделать возможность платной отмены рекламы и подписки на уведомления. Уведомления шлет наш сервер. Через что это реализовать?

Comment: Покупки в приложении это [In-app Biling](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html). Уведомления шлёт ваш сервер, а в чём конкретно вопрос тогда?

Comment: @eugeneek, в том, чтобы уведомления приходили только тем, кто купил подписку. Я вообще не понимаю как тут все работает

Comment: После покупки подписки вы на сервере добавляете пользователю метку о там, что подписка куплена. Перед отправкой уведомлений сервер получает список пользователей с этой меткой, проверяет подписку у гугла и если всё ок, отправляет уведомление.

Comment: Какие пользователи? Я их не храню, контент общий, у меня не соц. сеть. Нельзя ли напрямую у гугла проверить? И вообще как это все делается?

Comment: Придётся начать хранить. Схема работы пушей в кратце такая: устройство регистрируется у гугла и получает id. Потом этот id вы сохраняете у себя на сервере и привязываете его к пользователю. При отправке пуша сервер отправляет гуглу данные и список id, которым этот пуш доставить. [Принцип работы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_push#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.BF_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.8B_.D0.B4.D0.BB.D1.8F_.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.9E.D0.A1)

Comment: @eugeneek, пуш у меня через OneSignal уже прикручен, гуглом тут и не пахнет

Comment: Неужели это так сложно? Сервер разве не может узнать у гугла купил ли юзер подписку или нет?

Comment: Может, и должен. Но вы же написали, что у вас нет юзеров.